# Blank Array Returned A Length of 5

Tags: javascript, arrays, reference-type

I have been watching PluralSight's Rapid JavaScript Training by Mark Zamoyta and I came across this. He showed these two examples. I've been trying to wrap my head around it, but still could not understand.

How is it able to capture the length of the entries after the array was created using `new Array()` method, seeing that it returned a blank array `[]`. If it's blank like this `[]`, shouldn't it return `-1`?

```
  var entries = [1,2,3,4,5];
  entries.length
  => 5
  entries
  => [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

  var entries = new Array(5);
  entries.length
  => 5
  entries
  => []
```

Comment: `new Array(arrayLength)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array. You should read the manual.

Comment: While the above link technically does describe why, it is buried in a lot of other documentation.  The key part is:  "If the only argument passed to the Array constructor is an integer between 0 and 232-1 (inclusive), this returns a new JavaScript array with length set to that number."

Comment: The part when you say `entries => []` is not true

Comment: @Luka I didn't say entries => []. I used repl.it and the native JS console returned that.

Comment: @putvande Thanks for the link.

Comment: @JonSG Thanks for pointing that key part out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var myArray = new Array(5);
```

When you define an array by passing the constructor an integer like above, memory is allocated for 5 slots in the array.  If you examine the array, you will find:

```
console.log(myArray[1]);
=> undefined
console.log(myArray.toString);
=> ,,,,
```

As you can see, there are indeed five elements in the array, each of them `undefined`.  So your array isn't "blank."

It is probably bad practice to initialize an array in this manner, as there just isn't a good use case for it.  Pushing to the array will yield:

```
myArray.push("value");
console.log(myArray.toString);
=> ,,,,,value
```

...which is never what you want.  I would advise initializing the array like below and forget that passing an integer to the constructor is even an option:

```
var myArray = [];
```

Comment: ". I would advise initializing the array like below and forget that passing an integer to the constructor is even an option:" -- upvote for that alone.

Comment: ^ I agree. I have been learning and using JS for over a year and I felt bad for not knowing this. Now I don't feel as bad since it's not commonly used.

Comment: There are occasionally reasons for instantiating an array with a preset length - a useful, though odd, example is creating a repeated-character string: `new Array(5).join('s') => 'ssss'`

Answer (score 1):

The `length` property of an array in JS is not calculated on the fly - it can also be set manually via the constructor or an assignment, and it's updated as objects are added or removed ([Spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4)):

> Specifically, whenever a property is added whose name is an array index, the length property is changed, if necessary, to be one more than the numeric value of that array index[.]

It's a plain property that's kept up-to-date, not a calculation. Using the constructor `new Array(5)` initializes an array with `length` set to `5`. You can also set it manually, which fills in `undefined` or truncates the array as needed:

```
var arr = [];
arr.length = 3;
// arr is now [undefined, undefined, undefined]
```